# Why does this result in concatenation rather than adding the two numbers together?

Tags: javascript

Why does this result in concatenation rather than adding the two numbers together, if I enter a number as input?

```
let theNum = n => n + 1;

let usrNum = prompt("Enter a number: ")

alert(theNum(usrNum))
```

Comment: prompt usually returns a `string`. to make this work you can convert it to a number first with `Number(usrNum)`

Comment: Interesting. Thank you!

Comment: @jcal `Number(usrNum)` is a bit overkill. Just prepend a `+` in front of the strings to be converted. `let usrNum = +prompt("Enter a number: ");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in JS, string + numbers = string. Try '+' before n:

```
let theNum = n => +n + 1; // or Number(n)

let usrNum = prompt("Enter a number: ")

alert(theNum(usrNum))
```